# Converting a JSGlobalContextRef to a JSContext

Tags: objective-c, javascriptcore, nativescript

I'm trying to run javascript through the NativeScript runtime. Using the C APIs, like in the [NativeScript example](https://github.com/NativeScript/ios-runtime/blob/master/examples/BlankApp/main.m#L41) works well, but I'd like to use the Objective-C API. I'm having trouble converting the `JSGlobalContextRef` of the runtime to a `JSContext*`. I first tried bridging.

```
JSGlobalContextRef ref = runtime.globalContext;
JSContext* context = (__bridge_transfer JSContext*)ref;
[context evaluateScript:@"var x = 1;"];
```

but it doesn't appear the types are bridged. It fails with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the last line. I then found the `contextWithJSGlobalContextRef:` method and tried:

```
JSGlobalContextRef ref = runtime.globalContext;
JSContext* context = [JSContext contextWithJSGlobalContextRef:ref];
[context evaluateScript:@"var x = 1;"];
```

This time it fails on the second line with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. What is the correct way to get a `JSContext*` from a `JSGlobalContextRef`?

Comment: I think contextWithJSGlobalContextRef is not working because we build JavaScriptCore without the Objective-C API.

Comment: So the JavaScriptCore that NativeScript uses is different than the one included in iOS? Maybe I'm using the wrong Framework? Cmd-Clicking `JSGlobalContextRef` brings me to the JSBase header in Apple's framework

Comment: Yes, you can see it here: https://github.com/NativeScript/ios-runtime-jsc . That's just Xcode's navigation. If you put a symbolic breakpoint on say JSEvaluateScript, you'll see BlankApp`JSEvaluateScript.